# Button needed for a mobile internet connection won't work anymore even after reinstallating. What could be the reason?

Tags: windows, networking, internet-connection, flash, adobe-flash

My mom travels frequently and for that reason she uses a Windows 7 notebook and mobile internet dongle to connect to the web. It uses a little USB modem that I assume works like any smartphone because it uses a chip like one inside of it. You install a software that do the middleman work.

It is a rather old thing though, and looking into the folder where it is installed on Program Files it has many `.swf` extension files, so I assume the interface was made in Shockwave Flash? I'm not sure though.

The problem is that a while ago — without any out of ordinary use of the notebook — the "Connect" button that you have to click to give permission to start using available data stopped working and it keeps on a gray hue, usually it turns blue when it finds everything (which it does).

I tried to reinstall it, uninstall antivirus, check firewall permission, check if there was any leftover content on the disk like "AppData" hidden folder and restart the notebook after uninstalling again.

I thought it could be a problem with the provider, but it is not, it install and works normally on my PC, just my mom's notebook that it doesn't work anymore but all the other things I could check just looks the same, the network that it finds and will connect to, the antenna strength and signal; they all look the same on both systems, just the button really that you can't click on it.

I also tested if a normal Wi-Fi connection would work on this notebook and it works fine, so it seems it is not related to a network interface controller dying out.

This thing worked on this notebook for years and stopped working for no reason whatsoever and I couldn't find any other applications not working normally, so I don't think it is a hardware problem.

What could be causing this? Where I could look into and how should I proceed to be sure to reinstall it completely clean again so it works like it did on my PC??

Any related things with Adobe Flash I could do or to force a connection without the need to click the button to do so??

Thanks if anyone can help me, I would appreciate any idea, and sorry for explaining it like a layman, I tried my best.

Comment: Please edit your question: Without knowing the make and model of the USB modem there is not much anyone here can do to help.

Comment: I will see if I can fetch that, I don't have it with me now, but I will do it when possible. Thanks a lot for editing the details on whatever I didn't know the correct terms and stuff like that!